# Упаковка выборки из 2 таблица в JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, json

Добрый день. Второй день бьюсь над проблемой: необходимо вернуть JSON объект, для дальнейшей обработки в android-приложении. На сервере есть php-скрипт, который делает выборку из MySQL:

```
$NUM = $_REQUEST[PART_NUMBER];
$query = "SELECT * FROM PARTS_INFO WHERE PART_NUMBER = '$NUM' LIMIT 30";
```

Дальше все это дело передается в JSON:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $part[ID] = $row[ID];
        $part[PART_NAME] = $row[PART_NAME];
        $part[PART_NUMBER] = $row[PART_NUMBER];
  }

  echo json_encode($part);
```

При таком раскладе все отрабатывает нормально. А вот когда я пытаюсь взять данные из двух таблиц выборкой:

```
$NUM = $_REQUEST[PART_NUMBER];
$query = "SELECT PARTS_INFO.PART_NAME, PARTS_FEED.PART_F 
FROM PARTS_INFO, PARTS_FEED 
WHERE PARTS_INFO.ID = PARTS_FEED.ID_PARTS_INFO 
AND PARTS_INFO.PART_NUMBER = $NUM LIMIT 30";
```

Android Studio выдает ошибку (хотя выборка выдает то, что надо):

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
```

С php я не знаком. Но думаю, что я как-то не так наполняю массив. Подскажите, как быть, куда копать?

Обработка JSON объекта:

```
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success " + result);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            PART_NAME = (json_data.getString("PART_NAME"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: У Вас имена колонок изменились во втором запросе.  Как гипотеза, попробуйте новый запрос начать так `SELECT PARTS_INFO.PART_NAME, PARTS_FEED.PART_F as PART_NUMBER`. Я переименовал столбец в выборке из `PART_F` в `PART_NUMBER`

Comment: Не совсем Вас понял. Я меняю `$query = "SELECT * FROM PARTS_INFO WHERE PART_NUMBER = '$NUM' LIMIT 30";` на `$query = "SELECT PARTS_INFO.PART_NAME, PARTS_FEED.PART_F 
FROM PARTS_INFO, PARTS_FEED 
WHERE PARTS_INFO.ID = PARTS_FEED.ID_PARTS_INFO 
AND PARTS_INFO.PART_NUMBER = $NUM LIMIT 30";` Т.е. первый вариант я вообще не использую.
Если второй вариант я пробую сделать через phpMyAdmin, то выборка возвращается такая, какая мне нужна. Не могу понять, как второй вариант правильно занести в массив и вернуть JSON

Comment: `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $part[ID] = $row[ID];
        $part[PART_NAME] = $row[PART_NAME];
        $part[PART_NUMBER] = $row[PART_NUMBER];
  }` имена колонок указаны явно. В вашей выборке нет колонки `PART_NUMBER`. Я не утверждаю, что это решит вашу проблему. Просто первое что бросилось в глаза. Возможно это окажется вам полезным, возможно нет :)

Comment: заметьте, что если у вас `ID` и т.п. что большими буквами написано - не объявленные константы, то  у вас в логах куча нотисов по этому поводу пишется

Comment: Если у Вас версия MySQL-сервера 5.7.8 или новее, то он поддерживет JSON, и можно получать оттуда данные сразу в нужном формате не третируя PHP. См. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html И обратите внимание, что в первом запросе Вы обрамляете вставляемое `$NUM` кавычками, а во втором нет - это тоже может быть причиной, если не проверять валидность параметра.

Comment: У вас там явно что-то валится, и выдает на клиента совсем не JSON, а HTML с описанием серверной ошибки. Поэтому замените клиента на что-нить типа SoapUI или еще чего и протестируйте запросы.